# Python gives error when trying to extract a substring

Tags: python

```
index = 2
source = 'hello world'

print source[0,index]
```

The error is "TypeError: string indices must be integers, not tuple". How come *index* is not an integer ?

Comment: `print source[0:index]`. While `index` is an integer, `0, index` is a tuple (because of the comma). Just try typing `5,6` into a python interpreter to see :P

Answer (score 2):

Because in python when you give elements separated by a comma (without any brackets ) , they become tuple -

```
>>> 1,2
(1, 2)
```

If you want the substring from 0th index to 2nd index , you should use colon `:` [(Slice notation)](https://docs.python.org/2.3/whatsnew/section-slices.html) -

```
>>> index = 2
>>> source = 'hello world'
>>> source[0:index]
'he'
>>> source[:2]
'he'
>>> source[:index]
'he'
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use slice notation (`seq[start:stop]`):

```
>>> index = 2
>>> source = 'hello world'
>>> print source[0:index]
he
>>> print source[:index]
he
```